# Does Apollo client optimistic update changes reference for every list item?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

1. I have parent component **A** from where I am fetching TODO list **(lets say 10 item)**, then mapping this array and passing whole object to component **B**.
2. Component **B** has a **memo** wrapper to compare **todo** object references to re-render only updated component. Sth like:

   ```
   export default memo(ComponentB, (prevProps, nextProps) => {  
    return prevProps.TODO === nextProps.TODO
   })
   ```
3. From component **B** on button click call **useMutation** to add one item inside list. I provided **optimisticResponse** and **update** function as it was on **Apollo doc**
4. Everything is working fine except: When I am adding **optimisticResponse** for fast UI change and log inside component **B**, I see that every list item is re-rendering, **BUT** in case I just leave **update** function without **optimisticResponse** then I see that only one item re-rendered.

So my question is, is this how **Apollo** treats **optimisticResponse** update or I should continue looking for some issue in my code and I am trying to figure out hours already :/

I just couldn't found any material yet which points out this particular case and if someone knows answer, maybe share the link or small suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The optimistic response is committed to the cache, so you're logic will "think" that the data has updated. After the server responds, the cache is reverted and the real data is applied. So, in fact, you will experience 2 updates when you might have expected only 1.

Besides that, I believe you're saying that you have a component rendered for every "TODO" item. AKA, you're not passing an array to a single component. That sounds like the right method, just making sure that's what you have. So why do they all update? It doesn't seem like you need to worry about the apollo code for this issue. I think the first step is to change the line,

```
return prevProps.TODO === nextProps.TODO
```

to be a comparison that DOES NOT depend on references. Instead, the simplest quick change would be if there's some string ID field on the TODO. In that case you could do,

```
return prevProps.TODO.id === nextProps.TODO.id
```

This way you don't have to worry about whether apollo is returning the same reference or a new object with the same data. If that doesn't fix it, let me know in the comments and we can keep looking.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Yes of course if I compare only one field, lets say ID as you mentioned it will re-render only new one, but to compare object references would make more sense, because what if you need to update one field inside TODO object, then it means I have to increase separate field checks inside memo function and it might got bigger and bigger. That's why I was wondering does Apollo changes every TODO objects reference when using Optimistic response or not, because without optimistic response it re-renders only changed component.